# JQuery & PHP Lookup Field

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, html

I have followed a tutorial on how to create a look up field which dynamically searches a table in the MySQL database - the purpose is to process a contact lookup by postcode. I have the search working and the value (on the page) is inserted into the field however I need to get the id of the record selected into the value="idhere" parameter of the input field. I have added both the PHP and the HTML below can anyone take a look and help resolve my problem.

Javascript & CSS

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function getSuggestions(value) {
            if(value != ""){ 
            $.post("lookup.php", {contactPart:value}, function(data) {
                $("#suggestions").html(data);
                runCSS();
            });
            }else{
                removeSuggestions();
            }
        }

        function removeSuggestions() {
            $("#suggestions").html("");
            stopCSS();  
        }

        function addText(value) {
            $("#inputContact").val(value);
            $("#inputContact").val() {
                $(this).val()
            }   
        }

        function runCSS() {
            $("#suggestions").css({
                'border' : 'solid',
                'border-width' : '1px'
            });
        }

        function stopCSS() {
            $("#suggestions").css({
                'border' : '',
                'border-width' : ''
            });
        }
        </script>

        <style type="text/css">     
        #suggestions {
            text-align: left;
            padding-left: 3px;  
        }

        #link:hover {
            background-color: #f0f0f0;
            cursor: default;    
        }
        </style>
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="userA" id="inputContact" onblur="setTimeout('removeSuggestions()', 200)" onkeyup="getSuggestions(this.value);" value="idhere" />
<div id="suggestions"></div>
```

PHP

```
<?php 

mysql_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "root")or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("gEntry")or die(mysql_error());

$contactPart = mysql_real_escape_string(addslashes($_POST['contactPart']));
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, title, firstname, lastname, postcode FROM contact WHERE postcode LIKE '%".$contactPart."%'")or die (mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<div id='link' onClick='addText(\"".$row['id']. ' - ' .$row['title']. ' ' .$row['firstname']. ' '.$row['lastname']."\");'>" . $row['id'] . ' - ' . $row['title'] . ' ' . $row['firstname'] . ' ' . $row['lastname'] . ' - ' . $row['postcode'] .  "</div>";
}

?>
```

I am using standard mysql syntax as mysqli will not work on my server.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What "id here" I do not see that in your code

Comment: @mplungjan - I updated the code sorry

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where you want to put your id, but I'd suggest you to return json object so that you can then do what you want. I'd do:

```
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

    $json['id'] = $row['id'];
    $json['title'] = $row['title'];
    $json['firstname'] = $row['firstname'];
    $json['lastname'] = $row['lastname'];
    echo json_encode($json);
```

Then client side you could build your div and put your id where you want:

```
   $.post("lookup.php", {contactPart:value}, function(data) {
        var message = data.id+" - "+data.title+" "+data.firstname+" "+data.lastname;
        var resultdiv = "<div id='link' onClick='addText('"+message+"')>"+message+"</div>";
        $("#suggestions").html(resultdiv);
        //put your data.id where you need to put it
        $(this).val(data.id);
        runCSS();
        }, "json");
```

Comment: @pimvdb thanks for this so the json goes in the php? and the javascript replaces what i have?

Comment: @Justin Erswell: It was @Nicola Peluchetti who presented his idea, actually. Anyway, what happens is that PHP puts the data into a packet, sends it, and JavaScript will unpack it again into an object (so that you can access the `id` property). It is a convenient way of sending data.

Comment: @Justin Erswell yes the first part is in th php (i don't get just one thing: how many results do you expect?Just one?more than one?You should put checks on that). Anyway the idea is just to pack your data and return it to te client in a way that he can re-use: in your case you need the id twice it is handy to have it in a property of 'data'

Comment: Trying your code and no drop down but no errors either would you be a star and edit the code that I posted and insert your suggestions so that I may see how to formulate it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this part because it is invalid and not adding anything:

```
$("#inputContact").val() {
    $(this).val()
}
```

You can only use braces with `function() {}`, `if() {}`, etc. I'm not sure what you're expecting this to do, but what if you just remove these 3 lines?